# Alternative forms in second-person singular present active subjunctive

Tags: grammar-choice, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, conjugation

I am trying to translate "*plan [in order] to achieve*" into Latin.

[From the dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consequor#Conjugation) it looks like both "*meditator ut consequaris*" and "*meditator ut consequare*" are grammatically correct.

Are they, and if they are, what's the difference? Was the alternative form more popular in some geographic region or historical period?

Comment: @sumelic, thanks for the pointer, it answers my question!
Before I mark it as duplicate, does the translation look good to you?